# Redis Memorystore in GCP with all 3 option, AUTH + TLS Port + Non TLS Port

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, redis, tls1.2

I want Redis Memorystore in GCP with all 3 option, AUTH + TLS Port + Non TLS Port.
AUTH, to ensure password/key based authentication
TLS port, to be used by application which is used by internal user.
Non TLS port, to be used by backend application which is not directly is exposed to any user.

All (AUTH + TLS Port + Non TLS Port) options are possible on Redis on Azure, but it seems all combination is not possible in GCP. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. It is not possible to use all the three possibilities (AUTH + TLS PORT + NON TLS PORT) at a time. You can use any of them at once. Refer to this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/create-manage-instances) and enable using below syntax :

> **Redis AUTH** : To enable [AUTH](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/auth-overview), use the following flag:
>
> `--enable-auth`
>
> **In-transit encryption (TLS PORT)**: To enable [in-transit encryption](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/tls-encryption-overview), use the following flag:
>
> `--transit-encryption-mode=SERVER_AUTHENTICATION`
>
> When in-transit encryption is enabled Redis clients communicate
> exclusively across a secure port connection. Redis clients that are
> not configured for TLS will be blocked. If you choose to enable
> in-transit encryption you are responsible for ensuring that your Redis client is capable of using the TLS protocol.

**Non TLS PORT :**
If In-transit encryption is disabled then you can use Non TLS PORT which means Unencrypted communication between Redis client and server . You need to use a proxy to expose a non-TLS port for Redis.